# Mysql database import extremely slow

Tags: mysql, database, upload, wamp

I know this question has already been asked, but no answers seem to be helpful. I have a database containing 40,000,000 entries that I need to upload to wamp. I used the mysql command line and typed the following commands...

```
use database_name

source D:/pathtodatabase
```

It has been running all night and only uploaded 3,195,000 rows (1.3 Gib). What is a way I can speed up this import? I also know for a fact my computer is not a bottleneck as I am using a 7200 rpm drive and an i7-3770.

Comment: When I import a DB I always use this command: `mysql -u root -p database_name < path_to_sql_file/file.sql`

Comment: FYI, I'm not saying it works better. That is just what I use and I've never heard of your way.

Comment: 100 possible reasons. Start by telling us is it a MYISAM or INNODB database?

Comment: Have you done any mysql buffer Configuration

Comment: I haven't done any buffer configuration, how would I go about do that?

Comment: INNODB - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizing-innodb.html assuming its INNODB tables you are using

Answer (score 4):

Got the same issue when trying to import a large database. I tried several solutions and found [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/98814/mysql-dump-import-incredibly-slow-on-my-developers-machine/98815#98815) answer by Alex worked for me. Here is the complete process based on his suggestion (using Ubuntu 16.04):

1, enter mysql server

```
mysql -u username -p
```

2, change to the database that you want to import the data

```
use database_name
```

3, optimize the import operation, [more info here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html)

```
SET autocommit=0;
SET unique_checks=0;
SET foreign_key_checks=0;
```

4, import data

```
source path/to/datafile.sql
```

5, change back the default configuration

```
COMMIT;
SET unique_checks=1;
SET foreign_key_checks=1;
```